# How to fix the problem of "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable."?

Tags: python

I am trying to conditionally select all the cells in the range in excel by python, but this shows every time.`'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`
Is there a way to fix it?

I have already tried to put a `str` around `ws.cell(...)`, but it still does not work.

```
target_list = []

for i in range(1,20638):
    for j in range(1,49):
        if ws.cell(row = i, column = j).value[0:4] == "Drug":
            target_list.append(ws.cell(row = i, column = j).value[5:])
        else:
            pass
```

I expect to select all the cells that begin with the word `"Drug"`, but it shows `'"'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'` every time.'

Comment: Post properly indented code using the markup editor.  Your code is not readable as-is.

Comment: No way to tell exactly why without a [mcve], but one of the variables you are subscripting (denoted by the square brackets: `[]`), is `None`. [Do not share a screenshot of your data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), instead [edit] your question to include a small sample of your data.

Comment: Please mark the correct answer if your question was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a check before that line:

```
target_list = []

for i in range(1,20638):
    for j in range(1,49):
        if (ws.cell(row = i, column = j).value) is None:
            continue
        if ws.cell(row = i, column = j).value[0:4] == "Drug":
            target_list.append(ws.cell(row = i, column = j).value[5:])
        else:
            pass
```